# Ordenar a Tabela pelo valor mais próximo do parâmetro passado na stored procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, order-by

como ordenar uma tabela de acordo com o valor aproximado de um parâmetro passado em uma stored procedure

Ex:

digamos que em uma tabela o campo nome possui o seguintes valores: Tiago, Iago e Thiago e eu passo como parametro na stored procedure "Thiag", ele deveria me apresentar os dados na seguinte ordem:

1. Thiago
2. Tiago
3. Iago

Alguém conhece algo que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Isso vai ser pesado, pois vai ter que varrer todos os registros da tabela. Mas acho que utilizar uma procedure que utliza distância de levenshtein é um opção. Você pode colocar um limite de distância pra não devolver todos os registro caso queira. Qual o banco que você está utilizando?

Comment: Eu utilizo sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução para postgres seria a seguinte:

```
with ldist as (
   select name, 
          levenshtein(name, nameParametro)  as distance
   FROM names
) 
select * 
from ldist
order by distance;
```

Caso esteja utilizando outro banco de dados terá que ser adaptado.

Comment: Eu estou usando sql server

Comment: A ideia é a mesma, só tem que achar uma implementação do algoritmo de levenshtein para sqlserver.

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta: na query que me passou, qual dos name seria o valor a ser passado?

Comment: editei pra ficar mais claro. Na real tanto faz a ordem q vc coloca pois a distância entre as duas string será a mesma.